# Visual Studio não respeitando Templates ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Tenho um projeto `ASP.NET Core 2.2`
E dentro do projeto tenho a pasta Templates que possui meu Custom Scanfolding, por algum motivo ela parou de funcionar, já cheguei a utiliza-la muito.
Hoje após vários updates de packages, não funciona mais.

A Controller até é criada corretamente utilizando a template do projeto, porém as views não.
Para testes, atualizei toda List.cshtml do meu computador, colocando um `Create New 1,2,3` para cada versão que achei, mandei criar um arquivo novo e não usou nenhum dos mais de 8 locais encontrados *(tem no users\nuget\etc tem também no c:\programFile\etc e várias versões 2.0, 2.1, etC)*

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de o pq não utilizar mais as Views do Template?

**Update:**

Visual Studio 2019 16.0.2

Target framework: 2.2

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App: 2.2.0

Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 2.2.3

Comment: Qual a versão do Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools? Os templates ficam aqui: C:\Users\<usuario>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc

Comment: Veja que já mudei ai tbm..alias mudei em todos os lugares que tinha um List.cshtml no meu PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que como meu projeto foi criado com o `.core 1.0` e após updates do .net

faltava a pasta

```
Templates\ViewGenerator_Versioned\Bootstrap3
```

Assim antes ele usava o `\Templates\ViewGenerator` que foi substituído pelo acima.